# Google Drive API Retrieve Revision Difference

Tags: google-drive-api, revision

I am trying to get the differences between two distinct revisions of a file. I have tried both listing the "changes" and "revisions" resources provided by the API. However these resources do not seem to be having the information on the "differences" between two revisions. They simply return the specific revision's file content as the information.

The main goal here is to bypass the overhead of downloading the current state of the file and just fetching the differences (between the local version that I have) so that it can be applied to the local version of that file.

Is there any way to fetch **just** the differences?

Comment: I think you mean, the difference changes in the content of each revision. Do you?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to fetch just the differences?

No.

The workaround you suggested (download both file versions, then diff them locally) is the only way available so far.